# Button Hiding in Tabpage in Winform

Tags: c#

I have a TabContro in that i have Two Tabpages named tabInsurence and tabPersonal I have a button outside the Tabcontrol.
It display for one Tabpage and disable in other two tab page. I written this code but never
work

```
    private void tabPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Visible = true;
    }
    private void tabPersonal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: You shoul use another event - selecting.
Look in this [topic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926244/how-do-i-detect-a-change-of-tab-page-in-tabcontrol-prior-to-selectedindexchanged

Comment: Check in debug, you reach that  code or not

Comment: You have posted the exact same event twice in your question. I doubt that's what you intended, but it makes your question more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the selected index changed event to decide whether the button should be enabled or disabled based on selected index.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Enabled = tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: Or even better: `btnSave.Enabled = (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting it to visible. Is that the desired functionality? From your description it sounded like you wanted it hidden (or disabled) for one of the tabs.

Check to make sure your tab controls events are still attached to the methods (events in your properties box or just double click on the control).

Also, maybe try the Tab changing events on the tab control. The click events you are using may be intended for when a user clicks on the background of the tab page.